# Losing leading 0 in varchar field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script taking data from a varchar field in a MySQL db cell and, if certain conditions are fulfilled, adding it to another.

However, when the data is a number below 10, which in the original field is marked with a leading zero (e.g. 08), it saves it into the new cell as "8", causing me all sort of problems further down the line.

I know the query selecting the number maintains the leading zero - something happens when I run this:

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO gpvwc_DBSW.engine_allocation SET
        team_id=".$team_id.",
        car=2,
        event=".$nextEvent.",
        engine=".$previousengine2.",
        driver=".$Car2nr.";
        ";
```

The variable with the number is ".$Car2nr."; I know the receiving cell is supporting leading zeros as other queries leading to it do not have problem, but it's been two years and this is really doing my head in. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try to add quotes - `driver=' ".$Car2nr." ' ;`

Comment: ahhhhh! you need to use PDO or mysqli prepared queries

Comment: While the column may be a string, you're passing it in as an integer, because nothing is quoted. Use prepared statements and parameter binding ( [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) ), and you can specify that it's a string.

Comment: @questlooking and cmorrissey and aynber - thank you - I am not banging my head on the desk it was something so simple. This has saved me a lot of headaches!

Comment: I'll confirm it works next week - this script runs every other Saturday morning but I am confident the fix will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver=".($Car2nr<10 ? str_pad($Car2nr, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) :$Car2nr) .",
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP's `str_pad` function: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Example:

```
$Car2nr = str_pad($Car2nr, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

This will guarantee you always have a 0 before anything below 10.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PDO`](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo). If you aren't using an ORM like doctrine or one that comes packaged with a PHP framework, then you should use PDO.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8mb4', 'username', 'password');
$stmt = $db->prepare("
        INSERT INTO gpvwc_DBSW.engine_allocation SET
        team_id=:team_id,
        car=2,
        event=:nextEvent,
        engine=:previousengine2,
        driver=:Car2nr;
");
$stmt->execute(
    array(
        ':team_id' => $team_id,
        ':nextEvent' => $nextEvent,
        ':previousengine2' => $previousengine2,
        ':Car2nr' => $Car2nr)
);
$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

I think the above will work but to be safe you can `bindValue` and set the type:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':Car2nr', $Car2nr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```